# Spring data JDBC is not creating tables

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, spring-data-jdbc

I am trying to persist an entity called *Instructor* to H2 in-memory database using *Spring data JDBC*, if I create the tables manually everything works fine, otherwise I get this error (I added the entire error stack trace at the bottom):

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "INSTRUCTOR" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO "INSTRUCTOR" ("NAME") VALUES (?) [42102-200]
```

here is the entity class:

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;

@Data
@Table
public class Instructor{

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    
}
```

the controller uses this repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import test.com.small.school.model.Instructor;

public interface InstructorRepository extends CrudRepository<Instructor, String> {
}
```

the controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/add")
public class AddController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final InstructorRepository instructorRepo;

    @Autowired
    public AddController(InstructorRepository instructorRepo) {
        this.instructorRepo = instructorRepo;
    }

    @GetMapping("/instructor")
    public String addInstructorForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("instructor", new Instructor());
        return "instructor";
    }


    @PostMapping("/instructor")
    public String saveInstructor(@ModelAttribute Instructor instructor, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(instructor);
        instructorRepo.save(instructor);
        return "iresult";
    }
```

here is my application.yml:

```
    spring:
    datasource:
    generate-unique-name: false
    name: testdb
```

I thought the Spring data JDBC would create the tables automatically if they were missing, am I wrong?

here is the full length of the error I am getting:

```
    org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "INSTRUCTOR" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO "INSTRUCTOR" ("NAME") VALUES (?) [42102-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7628) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7599) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1747) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:954) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:815) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:76) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:1154) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:344) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.createPreparedStatement(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:231) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:991) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:356) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:340) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.executeInsertAndReturnGeneratedId(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:151) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.insert(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:127) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.executeInsertRoot(JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.java:94) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.execute(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:66) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.lambda$execute$0(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.DefaultAggregateChange.forEachAction(DefaultAggregateChange.java:116) ~[spring-data-relational-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.execute(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.store(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:339) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.save(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:150) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.SimpleJdbcRepository.save(SimpleJdbcRepository.java:60) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:599) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at test.com.small.school.control.AddController.saveDepartment(AddController.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Can you share application.properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Data JDBC does not offer automatic schema generation. You need to write the DDL yourself. See e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jdbc-intro

You may be thinking of Spring Data JPA, that does offer schema generation.